# Javascript HTML5 Array search and Return from HTML5 text box if in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, search

I am trying to input a name in textbox (html5) search values in array(javascript) and return value from textbox if it's in the array.

Basically I need to-- if search == arrayelement[i] display [i] else... Any guidance on where to start?

Comment: do u mean return value into another textbox?

Comment: No a return value from array if the searched name matches the array element

Comment: Or I guess the return value of array in another textbox would work

Comment: create textboxes and a button, assign ur array, on buttons `onclick` call a function say `search()`, return the number from that function if found.

Comment: googling "javascript searching arrays" would be a good place to start

Comment: What do you mean "in array" the input will always have a value of a string.

Comment: Awesome I appreciate the info. I was just using pseudo code when I said in array

Comment: I did try and search javascript searching and I found alot of info that returned the element number where the value is located. I wasn't sure how to convert that into the actual value. I will try the code snippet later when I get off work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of confusing, but I am guessing that you have an array of names, and you have a search input field that you want to search the array and then results (to a div maybe?).

```js
var names = ["john", "bob", "kayla", "sam", "elena", "josh", "andrew", "maria"];

function search(){
  var searchFor = $("#search-input").val();
  var searchIndex = names.indexOf(searchFor);
  if(searchIndex == -1)
    $("#search-results").html("no results");
  else
    $("#search-results").html(searchFor);
}
$("#search-input").on("keyup", search);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search-input' />
<div id='search-results'></div>
```

If you want to make this a little more interesting with each entry having its own url and allow partial searches try something like this:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: "John Smith",
    url: "http://example.com/johnsmith"
  },
  {
    name: "John Johnson",
    url: "http://example.com/johnjohnson"
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Thompson",
    url: "http://example.com/bobthompson"
  },
  {
    name: "Smith Sanchez",
    url: "http://example.com/smithsanchez"
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Sanchez",
    url: "http://example.com/bobsanchez"
  }
];
$("#search-input").on("keyup", function(){
  var searchFor = $("#search-input").val().toLowerCase();
  var results = [];
  for(var i=0;i<people.length;i++){
    if(people[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFor) > -1)
      results.push("<a href='"+people[i].url+"' target='_blank'>"+people[i].name+"</a>")
  }
  if(results.length == 0)
    $("#search-results").html("No Results Found");
  else
    $("#search-results").html(results.join("<br>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='search' id='search-input' placeholder='Search' />
<div id='search-results'></div>
```

Comment: That would be a great idea. I am going to dig into this all when I get off work.

Comment: I actually am trying to get the above code working in Notepad. I am having difficulty getting it to run. I've included the library and all the html tags but all that appears is the text box. None of the searching features are working.

Comment: Did you include the JS at the end of the body?

Comment: Javascript library is before the </body> tag at the end

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: Okay. I have worked all day and am probably just tired and missing something. I appreciate the link.

Comment: I got it working. Simple mistake on my end from being super tired. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
    var arr = new Array(10);
    arr = [23,14,535,346,54,65,2,1,3,5];
    function search(){
        var i=0;
        var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
        while(i<10){
            if(arr[i]==key){
                document.getElementById("result").value = key;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(i==10){
            document.getElementById("result").value = "Not Found!";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="key"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="search()" value="Go"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="result"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfun() {
  var search_string = document.getElementById('search_string').value;
  var arrayelement = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"];
  for (i=0;i<arrayelement.length;i++) {
 if(search_string==arrayelement[i]){
  var flag=1;
 }
  }
 if(flag==1){
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Item found";
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Item not found";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search_string" />
<button onClick="myfun()">Start</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Wow this is looking pretty good here. I am going to get in and go line by line on this when I get off work. Much appreciated

Comment: I really appreciate all the comments!